# Unable to determine a device of iOS simualtor

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

1. I have upgraded Xcode version from 6.4 to 7.1.
2. After updating the Xcode , I have created a simulator with 9.1 as platform version.
3. I have launched the simulator via Xcode, but it shows as Unable to determine a device.
4. I am attaching the screen shot for reference.[image]